# Kafka - Transmitting large media content

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a requirement to continuously transmit large video files from one system to another. Is Kafka suitable for transmitting large media content? What are the considerations that I must take into account before opting for this solution?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Kafka to send messages which point to an external reference to the large video files. Then the receiver can dowload the new file from this external storage (like for example Amazon S3 buckets). This is called the "Claim Check Pattern" and is documented here http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/StoreInLibrary.html

However, Kafka is not designed to transport the large video files themselves. It is not a managed file transfer tool.

Answer (score 1):

You could chunk up the files and put each chunk as a message into Kafka then recombine the chunks on the other end. By default Kafka message size is 1MB. This is configurable.

Comment: Thank you! Is it common based on your experience to follow this approach for transmitting video files ?

Comment: Just make sure all the chunks go to the same topic partition (via a common key) or you will lose the ordering of all the chunks and corrupt the file. Even with a single partition topic you would also need to set max.inflight.messages to 1 to avoid out of order publishing due to retries

Comment: Come to think of it, you could still get duplicate chunks since Kafka is "at least once" for producers. At least until 0.11 is out.

Comment: @HansJespersen can you clarify what you mean by "at least once" for producers?

Comment: @HansJespersen do you actually mean set 'max.in.flight.requests.per.connection' to 1? if so an alternative is to turn off retries on the producer end.

Comment: @bhspencer yes max.in.flight.requests.per.connection is the correct parameter name. This must be set to 1 to ensure strict ordering of messages. The default is 5 so your client can send up to 5 messages at a time and they may commit in the topic in any order. "At least once" means that Kafka can get duplicate messages in some cases when there is a network outage or a system crash.

Comment: LinkedIn wrote a tool to do this and have a slide deck that talks about all the issues they had to consider https://www.slideshare.net/JiangjieQin/handle-large-messages-in-apache-kafka-58692297 The code is here https://github.com/linkedin/li-apache-kafka-clients/blob/master/README.md